# Calculate width of user submitted image(s) before fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, ribbon

I have a series of images generated by users which are fed into a draggable ribbon. I am setting the height of the images so that they line up nicely with each other and display them in a line.

The problem I am facing is that I need to wait for all of the images to load before I can calculate the width of the ribbon and set some draggable paramaters based on the ribbon width... and in some cases this takes 5+ seconds.

Is there a way to wait until all of these images have **started** loading and then get the width of the ribbon... so that if there is only the first 10 vertical pixels loaded of a large panoramic image it will still be able to do the calculation.

I am using jQuery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `load` event:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //...
})
```